# Need to float a Pinterest board to the right

Tags: css, css-float, styling, pinterest

trying to get a Pinterest board to float right.  whenever any styling is applied to the span or Pinterest board it does not render  - this should have been a 2 minute job.  See here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lx07fe43/

```
<span style="float:right"><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pinterest/official-news/" data-pin-do="embedBoard" data-pin-board-width="400" data-pin-scale-height="240" data-pin-scale-width="80">_</a></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply 'text-align:right' rather than float:

Updated fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/qaj25bkf/

```
<div class="float-right">
<a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pinterest/official-news/" data-pin-do="embedBoard" data-pin-board-width="400" data-pin-scale-height="240" data-pin-scale-width="80">_</a>
</div>

.float-right {
text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: Yeah tried that one - but need the text to be wrapped around the grid - strange one

Comment: @amun1000 It's probably some weird JS-Fiddle thing. This does indeed work. [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mcbfvffd/)

Comment: I got this working. I added a width and 'overflow:hidden' to the Pinterest board div. Updated here https://jsfiddle.net/qaj25bkf/1/ The board is floated right with the text wrapping around it.